# In associative arrays, assigning index and value at the same time

Tags: bash, array

In a bash script I found the following but though it works I cannot understand its logic

```
REMOTESNAPS+=(["$FS"]=" $SNAP")
```

The statement above adds an element to the associative array `REMOTESNAP` by defining which index "`$FS`" must be used and by adding the second element "`$SNAP`" to it.

I could not find an explanation for such smart way to build associative arrays nor the point in the manual of bash where it's explained or I can deduce it.

Can somebody expand this topic? It'll be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "PARAMETERS" section in `man bash`, see

> In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value  to  a  shell
>          variable or array index, the += operator can be used to append to or add to the
>          variable's previous value.  When += is applied to  a  variable  for  which  the
>          integer  attribute has been set, value is evaluated as an arithmetic expression
>          and added to the variable's current value, which is also evaluated.  When += is
>          applied  to an array variable using compound assignment (see Arrays below), the
>          variable's value is not unset (as it is when  using  =),  and  new  values  are
>          appended  to  the array beginning at one greater than the array's maximum index
>          (for indexed arrays) or added as additional key-value pairs in  an  associative
>          array.

Comment: Thanks Choroba, I'll stick to the syntax shown above to avoid any weird bash behaviour,

Answer (score 0):

Just a link where I found an example of what explained in the man bash. Search for "Individual mass-setting for associative arrays. The named indexes (here: S1 and S2) are strings."